# How to run python script in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

For some reason unknown to me section CMD does not work, but if I run the script by going into the container, it works.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN mkdir /home/bob
WORKDIR /home/bob
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN echo "pyodbc" > /tmp/req.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/req.txt
# Will attached to /home/bob/folder1 in container (folder0 contain files and folder with test1 name)
ADD ./folder0 ./folder1
RUN chmod ug+x /home/bob/test1
CMD [python3 /home/bob/test1/bin/start.py &> /home/bob/test1/status.log]
# CMD tail -f /tmp/req.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?
ps: just started learning docker

Comment: Try to use this line `CMD ["python3", "/home/bob/test1/bin/start.py", "&>", "/home/bob/test1/status.log"]` i.e. separating each space separated setting with a comma and enclosed with a comma.

Comment: Note that JSON-array "exec" form does not run a shell; `sys.argv[1]` will literally be the string `&>` and there will not be a redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script named `start.sh` like this:

```sh
python3 /home/bob/test1/bin/start.py &> /home/bob/test1/status.log
```

Then update your docker file as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN mkdir /home/bob
WORKDIR /home/bob

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN echo "pyodbc" > /tmp/req.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/req.txt

# Will attached to /home/bob/folder1 in container (folder0 contain files and folder with test1 name)

ADD ./folder0 ./folder1
RUN chmod ug+x /home/bob/test1

COPY start.sh .
RUN chmod a+x start.sh

CMD ./start.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, `CMD` can have two forms.  The [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) must be a JSON array, with individual words double-quoted; you are responsible for breaking the command into words, and you cannot use shell forms like redirection.  The [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) does not have extra punctuation and implicitly wraps its command in `sh -c`, but can use all shell features.  (These links are to `ENTRYPOINT` examples but the same syntax works for `CMD` and also `RUN`.)  Your example has square brackets, like the exec form, but not double-quotes; you should just remove those.

Stylistically, remember that a Docker image has an isolated filesystem.  You generally will want to build a working Python application on the host and then package it in a container; so use the `requirements.txt` file from running `pip freeze` on the host, rather than trying to rebuild it from scratch in the Dockerfile.  Similarly, since the image is isolated, it doesn't usually make sense to have a "home directory", and since the container will also have an isolated filesystem, it doesn't make sense to capture the process's output to a file in the container that will be hard to read later.

I'd rewrite this Dockerfile as:

```sh
# Use the standard Docker Hub Python image, rather than installing
# Python on an Ubuntu image.  (You may have a specific requirement
# to use specific base images.)
FROM python:3.9

# Use a short directory name.  Don't make it look like a user's home
# directory.  This will automatically create the directory for you.
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python package dependencies.  The base image will already
# have pip installed.  Do this as a separate step, so that it can
# be cached on rebuild if the requirements.txt file hasn't changed.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application in.  You can rename things here if
# you really need to, but it can lead to confusing differences between
# your development environment and the deployed application.
COPY . .

# The main script should be executable on the host system (run
# `chmod +x start.py`) and start with a shebang line
# #!/usr/bin/env python3
# so you should be able to just
CMD ./start.py
# without any redirections or any special punctuation
```

If you just `docker run` the built image, it will print its output to stdout; if you `docker run -d` the image in the background, `docker logs` will be able to retrieve its logs.